# Obtaining the column width in tabularx

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I'm trying to align vertically the content of cells, for which I'm using the multicolumn command. The problem is that I need to set the width of the text for the `m` parameter, but I don't know how to get this if the column has an `X` attribute for expanding that column till the width of the page (`\columnwidth` doesn't work, and `\linewidth` gives me too much width). The code I have so far is

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{booktabs} % commands for table rules
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\scell}[1]{\cellcolor{black!25} \bfseries #1 }
\newcommand{\slcell}[1]{\cellcolor{black!25} #1 }


\begin{document}

\noindent
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}% Spread rows out...
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm}|>{\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.1cm}|}
\hline 
 \scell{Header 1} & \scell{Header 2} &  \scell{ Header 3}  \\
\hline \hline
Cell 1 &\multicolumn{1}{m{4cm}}{ \lipsum[1]}  &  test \\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `\multicolumn{m{some length}}`  since `X` column type their contents as paragraphs?

Comment: I need vertical alignment

Comment: Do you mean centred? top-aligned?

Comment: Yes, center-aligned vertically, for which I need to use `m`

Comment: Then Mico's solution works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
\multicolumn{1}{m{<some still-to-be-determined length>}}{\lipsum[1]}
```

I would execute the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
```

in the preamble (*after* loading `tabularx`, naturally) and then write

```
\lipsum*[1]
```

in the cell in question.

*Longer explanation, as requested by the OP*: The `tabularx` environment in your example contains 1 column of type `X` and 2 columns of type `m`. An `X`-type column is, by default, just a `p`-type column whose width is calculated automatically by LaTeX. Importantly, `p`-type columns have their material top-aligned. As a (probably unexpected!) by-product of this setting, the material in the 2 columns of type `m` will not be vertically centered in general. (If the height of the material in the `X` column exceeds the heights of the material in both `m` columns -- as is the case in your example -- the taller of the 2 `m`-type columns will be top-aligned, the shorter of the 2 `m`-type columns will be vertically centered relative to the taller `m` column, and the placement of the `p`-type column will be different still. Ouch!) By running the instruction `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}`, the underlying type of the `X` column is changed from `p` to `m`, and the desired result comes about, i.e., all 3 columns get vertically centered in the expected way.

Moral of the story: The frequency of puzzling (and likely unexpected and unwanted) placement outcomes drops sharply if the underlying type of all columns is the same, i.e., all-`m` or all-`p`. Mixing column types is likely to cause quite some frustration.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\scell}[1]{\cellcolor{black!25}\bfseries #1}
\newcommand{\slcell}[1]{\cellcolor{black!25}#1}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % localize scope of this command
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{% require "\arraybackslash" in final column only
   | m{2.4cm} | X | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.1cm} |}
\hline 
\scell{Header 1} & \scell{Header 2} & \scell{Header 3}\\
\hline 
\hline
Cell 1 & \lipsum*[1] &  test \\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works nice! But I don't understand why. Could you please briefly explain in the answer?

Comment: @aaragon - I've posted an addendum to my answer, in which I explain what's going on in a bit more detail.